# Where is my new Subversion when installing from MacPorts?

Tags: macos, svn, macports

On my MacBook, the default SVN client was the version 1.4, and I installed *subversion* (ver. 1.7) from MacPorts. But when I run `svn` from terminal, it still launches the old SVN 1.4.

`echo $PATH` gives `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin`

`which svn` gives `/usr/bin/svn`.

I just noticed that MacPorts failed to install some dependencies, so SVN was not installed properly.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`, what's the output of `which svn`? What's the output of `find /opt/local -name svn`?

Comment: @DanielBeck: I edited the question

Comment: Errrr just noticed that macports failed to install some dependencies, so svn was not installed properly (`apr`)

Comment: `port installed` would have been my next suggestion :-) You could probably profit from a shell that displays the last command's exit code like I present here: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/21/customizing-your-bash-command-prompt/

Comment: just installed subversion with macports.  It does indeed get put in /opt/local/bin.  Did you type rehash?  Did you open a new shell?

Comment: Jakub, is your problem solved now? Or are you still stuck at installing the dependencies?

Comment: Nope, still fighting... I found that `apr` is a common problem but I didn't find you how to handle that